# Encrypt individual rows in database table with different passwords

Tags: mysql, oracle, sqlite, postgresql, nosql

Can we encrypt individual rows in database tables with different passwords. If yes, which database supports such feature. Each row contains client information, and I want to encrypt that row with the client details. 
No-SQL can also be considered for this, if that is possible in that.

Comment: Rows contain data. Each piece of data can be encrypted with a different password. Store encrypted data in table. Problem solved.

Comment: For Oracle, look into either transparent data encryption(TDE) or tablespace encryption (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asotrans.htm#ASOAG610 , http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asotrans.htm )

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to provide detailed guidance, when I don't really understand what the intent of the application is.

It's certainly possible to do what you suggest, though it may require some coding to achieve.

However, if you're just interested in making sure clients can only see their own data, an alternate approach may be VPD (Virtual Private Database) or RLS (Row Level Security).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am no DBA, but I believe with RLS or VPD, if your database is broken, your user data is breached. Consider credit card data for example, the intent here is for user to be able to see or modify its own row, and even if the database is breached, the data is encrypted for each user with their passwords. Now I don't want to encrypt every single field and put into DB. I want DB to take care that the question, as opposed to other answers which are obvious to encrypt data and then store it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend encrypting the data locally prior to sending to the database.  The other option is to provide different schemas for each client.